# Using Reflection To fill out PDF Form- ItextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, reflection, itext

I am trying to fill out a pdf form using reflection as below:

```
// Get the form fields for this PDF and fill them in!
 var formFieldMap = GetFormFieldNames(pdfTemplate);

     foreach (var fields in formFieldMap)
       {
         var fieldName = UppercaseFirst(fields.Key.Replace("pdf_", ""));

         var proPertyValue = fosques.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(ques, null);

          formFieldMap[fields.Key] = proPertyValue.ToString();

         }
```

This works fine for first property, but on second iteration it say `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`

Should I create another collection of fields, or can I avoid this?

Comment: Whenever iterating over some collection, you should not change the structure of that collection in the process (and assigning a new value to an existing key in such a map is changing the structure). Thus, either first create a shallow copy of the collection in question or collect the changes you want to make in another collection and apply them all after the foreach loop over the original collection finished.

Comment: @mkl thanks what you mean by shallow copy?

Comment: A shallow copy of a collection creates a new collection which contains the identical objects as the original. A deep copy, in contrast, creates a new collection containing (deep) copies of the objects the original one contains.

Comment: @mkl thanks any change of showing an example of shallow copy as right now I am doing  var formFieldMap = GetFormFieldNames(pdfTemplate);
             var formFieldToFillCopy = GetFormFieldNames(pdfTemplate); <-- this would be deep copy right?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know your `GetFormFieldNames` method. If it creates a new collection on each call, the second call essentially creates a copy of the result of the first call. Whether it's deep or not depends on that method, too. My proposal to use a shallow copy, BTW, was made merely to save resources. A deep copy would do the trick, too, it merely requires more resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the list you are enumerating through inside the enumeration.

You don't need to get `formFieldMapy[fields.Key]` because you already have access to it, so you could simply do:

```
foreach (var fields in formFieldMap)
{
  var fieldName = UppercaseFirst(fields.Key.Replace("pdf_", ""));

  var proPertyValue = fosques.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(ques, null);
  fields.Value = proPertyValue.ToString();
  //formFieldMap[fields.Key] = proPertyValue.ToString();
 }
```

The above does the same thing, it just doesn't directly modify what you are enumerating.

Comment: if i do it this way i get :Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>'

Comment: @Sam1 Well in that case, it never would have worked because you need to call `.Value` on the end of `formFieldMap[fields.Key].Value = ""`. See my edit.

Comment: still it says value hasn't got a setter

Comment: That is because `Value` must be `readonly`. In this case, what you are trying to do will not work in any situation, because `formFieldMap[fields.Key]` is the exact same as `fields`...

Comment: so in this case should i create another collection ?

Comment: @Sam1 No, this issue will remain even if you copy the collection. Please read what I am saying...

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the `formFieldMap` inside the `foreach` loop which is the base for iteration . Thats the reason it stops iterating for second time. So you have to maintain a separate variable to collect those values inside the loop and append it to `formFieldMap` once you are done with looping.

Comment: yea I will create another collection and map the fields to that and pass that as my collection...+1

Comment: @Sam1 although this will work, why create the same instance of something in memory when there is no need? You have access to everything you need in the loop as it stands, as I said :)

Comment: @LukeHennerley but the issue is i cannot set the value as there is no setter(please see the comments)